# Why does print function print round brackets? (ex: << print(i, "this number is even") >> output: << (1, 'this number is even') >>

Tags: python-3.x

The code i'm showing you is really simple and it isn't the one i'm working with, but it perfectly explains the problems i'm having with my other program.

I will post the code in order to simplify my problem.
Some parts of the code need to be posted in italian because i have also a problem while printing special charcaters (character - è), but there s the translation right after in the comments

my code

```
# ! /usr/bin/env python

#-*- coding: utf8 -*- 

for i in range(2): 
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("I'm inside the if")
        print(i, "è un numero pari.\n") # i is even 
        continue
    print("Il blocco if è stato saltato, per cui...") # I'm outside of   the if
    print(i, "è un numero dispari\n") #i is odd
```

This is the result i get when when running the file.py :

```
Sono all interno del blocco if, per cui...

(0, '\xc3\xa8 un numero pari.\n')           [x1]

Il blocco if è stato saltato, per cui...    [y]

(1, '\xc3\xa8 un numero dispari')           [x2]
```

This is what it should print: (this is also what i get if I copy the code into the bash while running python)

```
Sono all interno del blocco if, per cui...

0 è un numero pari.

Il blocco if è stato saltato, per cui...

1 è un numero dispari
```

So now i have 2 questions:

1.) why do the two prints(x1 and x2) print also the round brackets?

2.) why do [x1] and [x2] print "\xc3\xa8" instead of special charcter "è", like in line [y]?

Comment: You aren't using Python 3; this is the result of Python 2's `print` statement being given a `tuple` as the lone item to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may *think* you are using Python 3, but you aren't. You are using Python 2 and getting its `print` *statement*.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Dec  2 2018, 12:54:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(1,2)
(1, 2)
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(1,2)
1 2
```

The first command executes a `print` statement, printing the *tuple* `(1,2)`. The second command, after enabling the `print` function, calls that function with two arguments 1 and 2.

As part of printing the tuple, you are printing the *representation* of the string, not the string itself, which uses `\x..` to show non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I was not thinking about that.
Changed the Python default version in Ubuntu and it worked.

I used:

$sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code here (macos, python 3, "python3 file.py") and output is fine:

```
I'm inside the if
0 è un numero pari.
Il blocco if è stato saltato, per cui...
1 è un numero dispari
```

How are you calling your script? What is your environment?

Also on a side note rather than using if...continue, I would strongly suggest using if...else instead.

Answer (score 0):

what are you using for encoding? 
I tried it on Win 10, 64 Bit - i get this output:

```
for i in range(2):
if i % 2 == 0:
    print("I'm inside the if")
    print(i, "è un numero pari.\n") # i is even
    continue
print("Il blocco if è stato saltato, per cui...") # I'm outside of the if
print(i, "è un numero dispari\n") #i is odd
```

try to set the encoding in top of your file:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```